# How to convert a Regex result in a list?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I get a list of result of regex, in to a list?

I'll show my case as example: I have a the following HTML string code:

```
<div>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello Stackoverflow</p>
  <p>The book is on the table</p>
</div>
```

My regex filter is the following:

```
<p>(.*)</p>
```

The result that I'm looking for is the following list:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
<p>Hello Stackoverflow</p>
<p>The book is on the table</p>
```

How can I proceed to get that result?

Comment: I think [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246237/how-to-find-multiple-occurrences-with-regex-groups) answers your question. :)

Comment: You will have to use `capturing groups`.

Answer (score 3):

This gets us all the matches:

```
var allMatches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```

Let's convert this `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerable<Match>`. This is necessary because the `MatchCollection` class predates .NET generics:

```
var matchesTyped = allMatches.Cast<Match>();
```

Then we map the matches to the matched values and output the result into a list:

```
var matchedStrings = matchesTyped.Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

---

**TL;DR**

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should works for you:

```
string str = "<div>" +
                "<p>Hello World</p>" +
                "<p>Hello Stackoverflow</p>" +
                "<p>The book is on the table</p>" +
             "</div>";

string pattern = "<p>.*?</p>";

var matches = Regex.Matches(str, pattern);

var result = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value.Trim()).ToArray();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    //do something
}
```

I changed the regular expression adding `?` because it captures only one result from the first `<p>` until the last `</p>` in the string.